# program to give index of the repeating digit in array whose first appearance is on lowest index

Tags: c++, arrays, arraylist, integer, min

Question was given to me in online course

The question is:-

Given an array a[] of size N. The task is to find the first repeating element in an array of integers, i.e., an element that occurs more than once and whose index of first occurrence is smallest. Given an array a[] of size N. The task is to find the first repeating element in an array of integers, i.e., an element that occurs more than once and whose index of first occurrence is smallest.

input:-

```
7
1 5 3 4 3 5 6
```

output:-

```
2
```

explanation to output:-
5 is appearing twice and its first appearance is at index 2 which is less than 3 whose first occurring index is 3.

code is:-

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //entering array
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    //identification of numbers that are getting repeated
    int N=1002;
    int idx[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        idx[i]=-1;
    }

    int minidx=INT_MAX;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(idx[a[i]] !=-1)
        {
            minidx=min(minidx,idx[a[i]]);
        }
        else
        {
            idx[a[i]]=i;
        }
    }
    if(minidx==INT_MAX)
    {
        cout<<"-1"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<minidx+1<<endl;
    }
}
```

here in the code when I take the value of `N=1000` it gives expected output but it doesnot give any output at all for `N=1e6+2`

please tell me what is the problem

Comment: Probably a stack overflow. You may want to use a vector instead of the non-standard VLA: `int idx[N];`

Comment: `int a[n];` -- Replace this non-standard, fake C++ with `std::vector<int> a(n);`  Also, I suggest you learn C++ properly by using peer-reviewed C++ books instead of some online coding competitive website..  This: `#include "bits/stdc++.h"` is not a standard header.